# Windows 10 explorer.exe causing high disk usage and system hang

Tags: windows, performance, hard-drive, windows-explorer

One of my user is having a Windows 10 machine with Intel i7 processor and 8GB RAM. The issue is the explorer process is hanging while opening any folder or my computer. The user is running several instances of Visual studio and also running SQL management studio. The memory usage is only sticking around 2 to 2.5 GB only, meanwhile disk usage goes to 100%. I have checked the virtual memory and it is set to system default. The processes system and svchost is also taking high usage.

Comment: Have you checked in safe mode? Problem is still there.

Comment: Check whether your system is affected with virus.

Comment: If he's running multiple instances of Visual Studio and SQL Management Studio it sounds suspicious that it's only using 2-2.5 GiB of memory. Are you sure it's using all of those 8 GiB RAM? The resource monitor should show you which files are being accessed (maybe a lot of `pagefile.sys`?). Is it a constant issue or does it stop when he closes some application?

Comment: open a cmd.exe as admin adn run this command **wpr.exe -start CPU -start DiskIO -start FileIO && timeout -1 && wpr.exe -stop C:\HighDiskFileIO.etl** and capture the high disk IO. If you captured it, zip the HighDiskFileIO.etl and share it (Onedrive share link). I'll analyze what your Explorer is doing

Comment: The machine is not affected by virus, I have a centralized antivirus of Trend micro, i scanned the whole machine and no suspicious activities were found.